# How to check three vertices of triangle are in cyclic order or anticyclic order?

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry, coordinate-systems

***My goal Is to check normal's direction  of triangles in STL files are consistent??***

eg. 
STl file is as below, I want to check all facets are in same direction i.e. outward.??

**facet normal 0 0 -1**

```
outer loop
  vertex -20.5411 -4.36615 0
  vertex -16.9894 -12.3435 0
  vertex -19.1845 -8.54147 0
endloop
```

endfacet

**facet normal -0.994522 0.104528 0**

```
outer loop
  vertex -21 0 0
  vertex -21 0 2
  vertex -20.5411 4.36615 0
endloop
```

endfacet

I thought of calculating normal by cross product of vertices but how would i know the direction??

I read "Cross products of cyclic unit vectors are positive." but how should I use this rule in my problem??

Anyone can help me please?? I really get stuck here :(

Answer (score 1):

Check the sign of the dot product of normal and the cross product of 2 edge directions, e.g. given normal `N` and points `A`, `B`, `C`:

```
((B - A) x (C - A)) * N
```

The cross product should produce vector with the same direction as the normal and since the dot product of 2 vectors `S` and `T` is

```
S * T = |S| * |T| * cos(theta)
```

where `theta` is the angle between the vectors, this should be positive if and only if the direction is correct. (Assuming here that no 2 points of the triangle are at the same location)

Java code example(using [`javafx.geometry.Point3D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Point3D.html)):

```
boolean check(Point3D normal, Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3) {
    return p2.subtract(p1)
            .crossProduct(p3.subtract(p1))
            .dotProduct(normal) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian, But I don't understand how this will help me to check that all triangles of stl files are in same direction (facing in outward direction, according to right hand rule if the vertices are in anti-clockwise direction)??

One more thing, In few STL file there is no normal given by default, so i will be calculating by using cross product and then normalizing it.

Comment: Given  function by you compare two triangles...but how would I know which triangle is in correct direction in given set of triangles (i.e. which triangle is facing in outward direction??)
So that with I will take that normal as reference triangle and check with all remaining traingle.
Please let me know...I am so confused whole day

Answer (score 0):

Find the triangle with higher Z coordinate, check if the normal is almost outward (Z+ direction) or almost inward (Z- direction). Once you know this, just move to non-visited adjacent triangles checking if the normal flips and mark them as visited.

Once you visited all triangles, stop.

Comment: what is mean by almost outward or inward direction??
Can you give me please tell me how to know given triangle is facing in outward direction or inward direction??

Comment: You need to check if the angle between the world Z direction and the highest triangle's normal is close to zero.